# Trigger, Copy a column(which is used as a primary key) on insert to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of data that I export into a table.  It already has a primary ID(HAZ_ID) I want to be able to copy that column to another table with the same column name(HAZ_ID)  I tried creating a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableTokay_I
on dbo.test_tokay
after insert    
as
set nocount on

insert into dbo.edit(inserted.HAZ_ID/* Columns in table b */)
select a.HAZ_ID /* Columns from table a */
from
    test_tokay a
```

I try to insert it but it says dbo.edit cannot be NULL, so I'm assuming the data Im inserting into HAZ_ID in test_tokay isn't being sent to dbo.edit, how do i fix this?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of the important information to allow others to be able to answer this. I assume you are getting an error message? What is it? The syntax your insert looks a bit off...you don't use the value of inserted for the column name. You need to specify the columns in edit that you want to insert to. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need to do is take the value from your inserted table into your edit table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableTokay_I
on dbo.test_tokay
after insert    
as
set nocount on

insert into dbo.edit(HAZ_ID)
select inserted.HAZ_ID
```